# Mex Configuration in MATLAB for OpticalFlow.cpp code

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, gcc, mex

**Hello,
I am using the Optical Flow Matlab/C++ Code ([source code](https://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/)). I am using MATLAB under a Linux-Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit OS. In the configuration file it says:**

> Before compiling, please check project.h file in subfolder "mex". You don't have to do anything if you use Windows. If you use Mac Os or Linux, please uncomment the line  #define _LINUX_MAC.

**This has been done. Also it follows:**

> In Matlab, after you configure mex appropriately, change directory to "mex" and run the following command:

```
mex Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp OpticalFlow.cpp GaussianPyramid.cpp
```

**I think becuase of failing to properly configure mex  compilerin MATLAB, I recieve the following error after running the above mex-command:**

```
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2'. The version of gcc is not
supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list
of currently supported compilers see:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release. 
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2-19ubuntu1)'. The version of gcc
is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For
a list of currently supported compilers see:
 http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release. 
  Error using mex In file included from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync /yasharBTSync /Multimedi Recommender Systems/Video    Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow      /me   x/Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp:2:0 /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia Recommender Systems/Video Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/project.h:7:3: error: stray ‘#’ in program
% #define _OPENCV
 In file included from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia Recommender Systems/Video
 Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/Image.h:11:0,
             from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow   /mex/Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp:3:
             /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/Stochastic.h:11:13:
             warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
             [enabled by default]
 #ifndef _abs(x)

         ^
  In file included from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
   Recommender Systems/Video
  Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/OpticalFlow.h:4:0,
             from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow     /mex/Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp:4:
             /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/NoiseModel.h:6:0:
             warning: "PI" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832
   In file included from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia Recommender Systems/Video Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/Image.h:11:0,
             from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow   /mex/Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp:3:
             /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia
             Recommender Systems/Video
             Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow   /mex/Stochastic.h:16:0:
             note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PI 3.1415927 In file included from /home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia Recommender Systems/Video
 Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow    
 /mex/Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp:2:0:/home/labrador/Yashar_BTSync/yasharBTSync/Multimedia Recommender
 Systems/Video
 Classification/test_opticalFlow2/OpticalFlow/mex/project.h:7:1: error:
 expected unqualified-id before ‘%’ token
 % #define _OPENCV

^
```

**How can I solve this problem please?**

Comment: Wild guess...  Should say `#ifndef _abs` without the `(x)`.

Comment: Did you use "%" to comment a line in C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem when using OpticalFlow in MATLAB on a Linux server. I solve this by adding an option -compatibleArrayDims,

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp OpticalFlow.cpp GaussianPyramid.cpp
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).